# Max couldn’t go out after dark. <permission at a past time?>

Tags: modal-verbs, can-could, could, deontic-vs-epistemic

A linguistics paper titled "[Tense and Modals](https://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/stowell/Stowell-Tense&Modals.pdf)" by Tim Stowell shows these examples and explains them as follows:

> (9) a. *Carl can’t move his arm.* (ability at the utterance
> time) 
> b. *Carl couldn’t move his arm.* (ability at a past time)
> c. *Max can’t go out after dark.* (permission at the utterance
> time)
> d. *Max couldn’t go out after dark.* (permission at a past
> time)
> Example (9a) asserts that, at the utterance time, it is not
> possible for Carl to (habitually) move his arm. In (9b), *could*
> functions as a past-tense form of *can* in (9a); at some time prior
> to the utterance time, it was not possible for Carl to move his
> arm. **Examples (9c-d) work similarly.**

The last sentence in bold means:

> In (9d), *could* functions as a past-tense form of *can* in (9c); at some time prior to the utterance time, Max was not allowed to go out after dark.

But can *could* really convey the meaning of permission at a past time?

In (9c), it is the speaker who doesn't allow Max to go out after dark. But in (9d), it can certainly be someone other than the speaker who didn't allow Max to go out after dark. And the speaker can be merely conveying his past inability to go out after dark. If this is the correct interpretation, can (9d) still be said to convey "permission at a past time"?

Comment: Not sure that "In (9c), it is the speaker who doesn't allow Max to go out after dark." 9d is ambiguous and probably relies on context to indicate whether it means ability or permission.

Comment: @fev Do you mean 9c is ambiguous?

Comment: No, 9d. It can mean that Max was not able OR that he wasn't allowed. But I guess you could say the same about 9c, yes.

Comment: From CGEL : "Present tense 'can' is matched by 'could' in all the deontic and dynamic uses given in §9.3." Example given: " In those days we 'could'  borrow as many books as we wished. [permission]"

Comment: @fev You're right that both 9c and 9d can be ambiguous between the "ability" and "permission" reading. But when assuming that both 9c and 9d convey the "permission" reading, 9c can only be permitted by the speaker, but the same cannot be said, I don't think, about 9d.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "only by the speaker":  "Max can't go out after dark" is simply reportage: "Because of his parents' paranoia, Max can't go out after dark."

Comment: @user424874 Thanks for the quote! The present counterpart of CGEL's example is: _These days we can borrow as many books as we wish._ Now, do you think _can_ here conveys the deontic modality? Please note that, although the meaning of permission can be conveyed here, it's not the speaker's permission.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I suspect that it's "reportage"...not of someone else's permission but of Max's inability (arising out of  someone else's permission). In your example (_Because of his parents' paranoia, Max can't go out after dark._), does _Max can't go out after dark_ report his parents' permission or his inability (arising out of his parents' permission)?

Comment: Exactly. It's categorically not the speaker's permission.

Comment: *Max is not able to go out after dark because he doesn’t have a flashlight.*

Comment: @TimR [And the notion of "permission" has to be broadened to include things like "weather permitting" or "conditions permitting".] I think that's taking it a bit too far. Note that you can't really replace _couldn't_ with _wasn't allowed to_ in either of your examples without significantly changing their meaning.

Comment: @AndrewLeach JK2 It could very easily be the speaker's permission. I think what you are getting at is that whereas *can't* is often used performatively to declare that the speaker forbids or does not permit something, *couldn't* cannot be used performatively  in this way. However, it can clearly be used with reference to some past prohibition by the speaker. For example it might be a parent explaining that they didn't allow Max out after dark. And it could represent a reported speaker's permission: _The judge said Max couldn't go out after dark._

Comment: @Araucaria-Him First, your example denotes some past prohibition not by the speaker but by the judge. Second, as shown in, _The judge said Max mustn't/mightn't go out after dark_, backshifting is to be distinguished from past prohibition/permission.

Comment: @JK2 You mean the *second* example. How about the first? That's very, very clear cut :) The second example clearly says '_could represent a **reported speakers'** prohibition_'. [And reported speech backshifting doesn't exist. It's at best an illusory phenomenon. All that happens with so-called reported speech is that the information and not the speech is reported. This naturally entails that most often the clause reporting the information is in the past tense, or past perfect!]

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Sorry, but did you show me an example other than _The judge said Max couldn't go out after dark_?

Comment: @JK2 "For example, it might be a parent explaining that they didn't allow Max out after dark." in reference to (9d)

Comment: @Araucaria-Him So you're saying that (9d) "can clearly be used with reference to some past prohibition by the speaker". But (9d)'s _couldn't_ cannot be used performatively to declare that the speaker forbade or did not permit something in the past. It's merely reporting a past event.

Comment: @JK2 Well, no verb can be used performatively in the past. A performative is when the meaning's something like "I hereby forbid you ...." or "I delare theee man and wife" or "I dub you _Sir JK2_". Stuff like that.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him Exactly! That's why I posted the question in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

"*Could*" is used also as a modal for conveying the idea of permission in the past.

> **CoGEL¹ § 4.52 can/could** three major meanings of these modals can be distinguished.
>
> (a) POSSIBILITY […]
> (b) ABILITY […]
> (c) PERMISSION
> • *Can* we borrow these books from the library?
> • In those days only men *could* vote in elections.

In "(9c)" it is a matter of context whether Max has the permission to go out after dark. For instance, in "I know that Max can't go out after dark because his mother told me she wouldn't let him.", it is clearly Max's mother who does not allow it. The particular case to chose from "a" (possibility), "b" (ability)  and "c" (permission) is dictated by the context.

¹  <sub>A Comprehensive Grammar Of The English Language</sub>

Comment: +1 for CoGEL quote! CoGEL says this: "For the 'ability' sense, _can/could_ may be paraphrased by use of the _be able to_
construction...It is possible to paraphrase _can_ in the sense of permission by _be allowed to_: _Are_ we _allowed to_ borrow these books from the library?"

Comment: If the question _Can we borrow these books from the library?_ is directed to the librarian, it'd be more natural to paraphrase it as "Are we allowed to borrow...?" than "Are we able to borrow...?". But if it's directed to someone unrelated to the library, "Are we able to borrow...?" is also natural. Moreover, CoGEL says that you really can't replace _could_ with _might_ in _In those days only men could vote in elections._ If the deontic modality can readily denote past-time permission, why can't we use _might_ for past-time permission?

Comment: @JK2 It depends on context: if the question concerns books whose nature seems to be that of references, and if the person asking is not sure about this fact, then "be allowed to" is  the  more natural choice, as well as the proper one. However, if after some clarifications from the labrarian on a problem of availability of certain books, for instance as pertains to a peculiarly high frequence of borrowing, then "allowed to" is simply incorrect, and "able to + adverbial" is the proper choice ("Are we able to … at any time?").  (1/2)

Comment: @JK2 It is usage that makes "might" a very unlikely choice for "permission in the past"; I see no other reason. It is a modal that has been restricted in its usage for permission: "may" has been restricted to the first person; "might" is not much used anymore for so called "tentative polite" asking of permission. It seems that this modal has been subjected to a certain atrophy or never was fully endowed with the expected possibilities; research is needed so as to determine which. (2/2)

Comment: @JK2 I've certainly seen 'might' used deontically (subset permission), but it's rather old-fashioned. Examples: << may we one day wake up and find the state of Alabama, where all men might vote >> [[prayer of Martin Luther King Jr](https://prayerandverse.com/tag/freedom/)] '' // << [I] voted for the equal suffrage of California women. I voted that women might vote because I knew ....>> [[E S Stewart?; JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1011989)] Non–vote-related examples are harder to find, as the usage is/was pretty formal. Religious usages ('that all might go in') tend to be indeterminate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the examples, although I doubt they're true examples of 'past-time permission.' The first _might_ seems to be optative, which is to be distinguished from central deontic usage. Note also the phrase _where every man and woman might be able to..._ (I don't think central deontic _might_ can combine with _be able to..._). The second _might_ is not exactly past-time permission but rather backshifted permission.

Comment: @JK2 Yes, you're right. A temporal phrase such as 'in those days' is needed to force the 'were allowed to' sense (needed in addition to a situation forcing a permissibility rather than feasibility reading). I'll dig some more.

Comment: << The Pharisees belonged to religious communities with strict rules for admission. Groups that followed the two main rabbis, Shammai and Hillel, required a candidate to undergo a period of probation before they could be admitted. ... [T]he candidate had to prove his ability to follow the ritual laws ... [of which there were two subdivisions]. A person might undertake [to observe] only the second ... [set]. In that case he was a "Neeman", [an] “accredited one” with whom one might [= was allowed to] freely enter into commerce. >> ....

Comment: [[D L Stevens; Inspirational Reflections; p56](https://jesusisnomyth.com/Publications/Inspirational%20Reflections.pdf)]

Comment: Returning to the CGEL treatment: the breakdown of principal meanings of the modals can/could is good. I'd prefer a different term than 'possibility' though, as this is polysemous (_may perhaps happen or may not_: 'There's a possibility that John will come to the party" vs _is not inherently impossible_: 'There's certainly a possibility of landing a manned craft on Mars, but hardly of man reaching an exoplanet given modern technology'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Have you ruled out the term "feasibility" as an improvement over "possibility"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In _one might freely enter into commerce_, _might_ can also be replaced with _could_. But in CoGEL's _In those days only men could vote in elections_, _could_ cannot be replaced with _might_. So I don't know how your last example would help.

Comment: @JK2 'In those days only men might vote in elections' is fine, if rather formal/old-fashioned.

Answer (score 3):

It is the semantics that play a role here. The collocation *go out after dark* makes it more clear that it is about permission rather than having the ability to do so. The same explanation applies to both *can* and the past tense form *could*. However, there can be a context where *can/could* in "Max can/could go out after dark" would mean "is/was able to"; with the meaning having the capacity or time to do so.

*OED* lists the relevance sense of *could* as below and compares to *might* which was favored in the past. I'm also adding the earliest citation from 1539; and the last two citations from  1968 and 1996 of this usage of *could* from *OED*:

> **II.ii.
> The past tense *could* with temporal function.**
>
> **II.ii.12.** Expressing permission or sanction: was allowed to, was given permission to; = may v.<sup>1</sup> II.iii.17.
>
> For long regarded by grammarians as at best *colloquial*, and discouraged in favour of *might*.
>
> 1539
> At that tyme no bysshop coulde be in Rome, without the ful consent & confyrmacyon of themperour. 
> <sub>J. Gough, translation of J. Le Maire, *Abbreuyacyon Gen. Councellys* sig. G.ii<sup>v</sup></sub>
>
> 1968
> Her mother insisted she could not go to the Halloween parade on an empty stomach. 
> <sub>B. Cleary, *Ramona the Pest* vi. 133</sub>
>
> 1996
> Pierce, did you tell Bethany she could come with us? 
> <sub>T. Janowitz, *By Shores of Gitchee Gumee* (1998) 247</sub>
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “can, v.¹, sense II.ii.12”, September 2023.
>  https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/4904772818</sub>

Note: *OED* lists the same sense and the note for *can* also, comparing to *may*.

Comment: I don't have access to OED, so if there are any example sentences under the definition, could you show them in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

All modals have at least two meanings,

1. the Deontic reading, which deals with social and behavioral norms, including giving and withholding permission, obligations, and taboos. Examples

   - *You must be home by midnight.*
   - *She can go to the ball.*
   - *He should really call her.*
   - *If he will hand it in, it can be graded.*
2. the Epistemic reading, which deals with logic, (judgements of) probability, and expected (though not obligatory) behavior. Examples

   - *This must be the place.*
   - *This can't be the place.*
   - *He should be home by now.*
   - *The 8:15 will actually leave at 11:30.*

These are all hedged round with restrictions, irregularities, idioms, constructions, and exceptions; every modal has some, so there are no firm general rules.

For one instance, the epistemic sense of *will* (often called "the future tense", though it isn't) is not allowed in *if*-clauses, which means only the deontic sense (of 'be willing') occurs there.

- **If it **will** rain tomorrow, we'll postpone it*

For another, the epistemic sense of *can* is only allowed in negative environments; note that all the original examples given of *can* meaning "POSSIBILITY" are negative. Take out the negation and see what happens.

3. Finally, *can* has not only a negative-polarity epistemic sense and a deontic sense of permission, but also a third sense, often called the Dynamic, which refers to ability, and shows up sometimes with past *could*:

- *When I was young, I could do 100 pushups; now I can only do 95.*

"Permission at a past time" is somebody else's phrasing, and doesn't mean much. This is just ordinary ornery modal behavior.

Comment: What kind of modality's involved in these?: *If it will cure the cancer, then the cost doesn't matter* / *If it will bring the rebels to the negotiating table, I am prepared to hand in my resignation* etc?

Comment: Something like effects of human actions forcing future expectations in hypotheticals. I'd say they weren't deontic.